# ngx-spinner icon not showing Angular 13

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ngx-spinner

The spinner comes up on page load however the loading text is showing but the icon is not showing. I have followed the documentation but I can't seem to find the issue. This is a screenshot of what I see on the page
[image]
[image]

**package.json**

```
"ngx-spinner": "^13.1.1",
```

**angular.json**

```
    "styles": [
      "node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/ball-scale-multiple.css",
      "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
      "src/css/reset.css",
      "src/css/styles.scss"
    ],
```

**app.module.ts**

```
   import { NgxSpinnerModule } from "ngx-spinner";
     import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
          
   imports: [
      NgxSpinnerModule
   ],
   schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ngx-spinner
  bdColor="rgba(51,51,51,0.8)"
  size="medium"
  color="#fff"
  type="ball-scale-multiple"
>
  <p style="font-size: 20px; color: white">Loading...</p>
</ngx-spinner>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';

 constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    /** spinner starts on init */
    this.spinner.show();

    setTimeout(() => {
      /** spinner ends after 5 seconds */
      this.spinner.hide();
    }, 5000);

  }
```

Comment: Can you inspect element and check if how many instances of "<ngx-spinner>" element you have on DOM?

Comment: Added a screenshot of that

Comment: Seems to work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-sutyej?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: @A.Mac Is the above code the complete example? If not, can you reproduce the issue on stackblitz or github? Without complete example it is difficult to help.

Probably for debugging, you can add a console.log() statement above `this.spinner.hide()` to see if you even get to that point.

Also, do you have any errors in you console tab? It might give a clue.

Comment: Try to add [fullScreen] = "true" to ngx-spinner tag and check.

Comment: @Exception [fullScreen] = "true" resolved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### app.componet.html

Added **[fullScreen] = "true"** to *ngx-spinner tag*

```
<ngx-spinner
  bdColor="rgba(51,51,51,0.8)"
  size="medium"
  color="#fff"
  type="ball-scale-multiple"
  [fullScreen] = "true"
>
  <p style="font-size: 20px; color: white">Loading...</p>
</ngx-spinner>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue. you have to recompile the project (ng serve) after your added the  type="ball-scale-multiple"

then you can showing correctly

this also keep in mind

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check that you are adding the animation css (in my case  "./node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/ball-scale-ripple-multiple.css") to the correct "styles" array in angular.json -> It needs to be part of the "build" styles

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "rumen-plamenov-website": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/rumen-plamenov-website",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce", "output": "/tinymce/" }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/ball-scale-ripple-multiple.css"
            ],
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue(I am using Angular 13 version).

1. Go to styles.scss file and add the following:
   `@import '~ngx-spinner/animations/ball-pulse-sync.css'`;(i was using ball-pulse-
   sync.css style)
   Add your style accordingly
2. Remove if you have added any styles in angular.json inside styles[] array
   as it is not needed.
   Lastly, I assume you have already added the necessary imports in app.module.ts.

Answer (score 0):

For the **ngx-spinner** you also need to add to your imports array in **app.module.ts** the **BrowserAnimationsModule**.

From

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```